# How can I iterate dictionaries to get key and value in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, key

How can I iterate over a dictonary to get both the key and the value written out.

```
hey = {'a':67, 'b': 98}

>>>a-67
>>>b-98
```

No built in methods should be used. This is what I have tried so far.

```
for i in hey:
     print(i)

>>>a
>>>b
```

This randomly iterates only over the keys.

```
 for i in hey:
       hey[i]

 >>>67
 >>>98
```

This gives me the values.

Can i combine these two perhaps? How would that look?

Comment: Why the prohibition on built-in methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can print two items with the same statement:

```
for i in hey:
    print(i, hey[i])
```

If you want the output as `a-67`, you can also use

```
for i in hey:
    print(i, "-", hey[i], sep="")
```

Comment: I get `a-67`. Are you sure your dictionary looks like the one you posted?

Answer (score 3):

You could unpack the `items`, then use `format` to print out they key and value as you'd like.

```
>>> for key,value in hey.items():
    print('{}-{}'.format(key,value))

a-67
b-98
```

Comment: `items` probably counts as a "built-in method" and "should not be used", according to the question.

Comment: @LevLevitsky A method is going to have to be used at some point. Even indexing calls `__getitem__`, a built-in method.

Comment: @Alex Can't argue with that, but it doesn't prevent people from imposing arbitrary and/or ambiguous restrictions in homework assignments.